# Lattice in the Complex Plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the ring of Gaussian integers, and $0\neq z\in \mathbb{C}$ be a complex number. Show that $\Lambda = \{zw:w\in\mathbb{Z}[i]\}$ is a lattice in the complex plane, find a basis for $\Lambda$ and compute $\det(\Lambda)$.

I am able to solve this problem for specific values of $z$ but haven't been able to generalize for arbitrary $z$, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If $w = 0$, then $\Lambda$ is just a point. Suppose $w \neq 0$.

$\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a free-$\mathbb{Z}$ module generated $\{1, i\}$. So $\Lambda$ is generated by $\{w \cdot 1, w \cdot i\} = \{w, iw\}$. It is easy to check that $\{w, iw\}$ is a set of $\mathbb{Z}$ independent elements. Therefore, $w$ and $iw$ is a basis for a two-dimensional lattice.

Now, $\textsf{det}(\Lambda)$ is just the area of the fundamental domain of $\Lambda$, which is the area of the parallelepiped spanned by $\{w, iw\}$. Viewing $\mathbb{C}$ an $\mathbb{R}$ vector space and considering the dot product on the basis $1, i$ tells us that that $w$ and $iw$ are orthogonal. Therefore, $\textsf{det}(\Lambda) = |w||iw|=|w|^2$.